# Playing two sounds simultaneously c#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I am creating a WP7 application that requires various sound effects to be played (on button press) over looped background music. The background music is initiated by pressing Button 1 and loops fine. When I press button3 (triggers a sound effect), the sound effect overlays on the background music fine on first press. However, when I press button3 again, the background music stops. I cannot figure out why this might be happening!? I have pasted the relevant portions of code below. Would appreciate any help.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    SoundEffect soundEffect;
    Stream soundfile;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    static protected void LoopClip(SoundEffect soundEffect)
    {
        {
        SoundEffectInstance instance = soundEffect.CreateInstance();
        instance.IsLooped = true;
        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
        instance.Play();
        }
    }

    public void PlaySound(string soundFile)
    {
        using (var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream(soundFile))
        {

            var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
            effect.Play();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        soundfile = TitleContainer.OpenStream("BackgroundMusic.wav");
        soundEffect = SoundEffect.FromStream(soundfile);  
        LoopClip(soundEffect);
    }


    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlaySound("sound3.wav");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Did u try Threading or Background worker ?

Comment: This is the exact opposite of what kept happening to me in Java...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work if you are always working with Instances so change your code to this and it should clear up the problem:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{   

    SoundEffectInstance loopedSound = null;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static protected void LoopClip(SoundEffect soundEffect)
    {
        loopedSound = soundEffect.CreateInstance();
        loopedSound.IsLooped = true;
        loopedSound.Play();
    }

    public void PlaySound(string soundFile)
    {
        SoundEffect sound = SoundEffect.FromStream(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(soundFile, UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
        SoundEffectInstance instance = sound.CreateInstance();
        instance.Play();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SoundEffect sound = SoundEffect.FromStream(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"BackgroundMusic.wav", UriKind.Relative)).Stream); 
        LoopClip(sound);
    }


    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlaySound("sound3.wav");
    }

}
```

The above example assumes your sound files are set with Build Action = Content and are in the top level directory.

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately, I just tried your code and I am having the same original issue -- background music stops after button3 is clicked more than 2 times (first click of button3 works fine..)

Comment: @sv77 you are right.  I ran my code and duplicated your issue.  I have updated my code and it should now work for you.  The key is to keep the looped soundeffectinstance around in it's own variable.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to play each sound from a separate thread.

What seems to be happening here is that the different `Play` method calls are interfering with each other since they are in the same thread.

Try just putting the background music in a separate thread and see if that solves the problem you mention in the question. If so, split the others out as well.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please give me some more details on how to start a new thread? I have not done it before and can't seem to get it to compile. [Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart (LoopClip))];

Comment: From the code in your comment, you should instead be using `Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(LoopClip))` or something similar, and pass in the argument (`soundEffect`) using the facilities provided by `ParameterizedThreadStart`.

Comment: Still having problems: "No overload for LoopClip matches delegate." I was able to use ThreadStart to call a nonparametized function that then called LoopClip. However, I still had the same original issue when the program ran.. Should I be creating a new Thread in button1_Click or somewhere else?