# play two sounds simultaneously in Windows 8 Metro App (C#/XAML)

Tags: c#, audio, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I a Windows 8 Metro App (C#/XAML):
How can I trigger the same sound effect twice so that it plays simultaneously.

The second play should start before the first has finished.

Related questions are:

[Playing two sounds simultaneously c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747086/playing-two-sounds-simultaneously-c-sharp)
and [Play two sounds simultaneusly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240002/play-two-sounds-simultaneusly)

I found this class for XNA which does what I want, but is not available under Metro:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance.aspx

Answer (score 17):

Just create a separate media element for every sound effect.

(not sure I need to relocate the file every time)

```
  public async void PlayLaserSound()
    {
        var package = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current;
        var installedLocation = package.InstalledLocation;
        var storageFile = await installedLocation.GetFileAsync("Assets\\Sounds\\lazer.mp3");
        if (storageFile != null)
        {
            var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            MediaElement snd = new MediaElement();
            snd.SetSource(stream, storageFile.ContentType);
            snd.Play();
        }
    }
```