# Unable to play sound in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I want to play sound from a mp3 file in windows 8 metro-style app. I tried two approaches to do so:

Method1:
This is using the code provided by https://stackoverflow.com/a/10961201/147530. It works.

Method 2:
Here I just new a `MediaElement` and set its `Source` property like so:

```
var x = new MediaElement { Source = new Uri("ms-appx:/Assets/MyMp3File.mp3") };
```

When I do `x.Play()` nothing happens however. There are no exceptions thrown.

Question: How can I make method 2 work?

EDIT:
Wanted to update that none of the `MediaFailed, MediaOpened, MediaEnded` event handlers get called using Method 2.

```
sound = new MediaElement { Source = new Uri("ms-appx:/Assets/Clook.mp3") };
                    sound.MediaFailed += sound_MediaFailed;
                    sound.MediaOpened += sound_MediaOpened;
                    sound.MediaEnded += sound_MediaEnded;

static void sound_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
        }

        static void sound_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
        }

        static void sound_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried: ms-appx://Assets/MyMp3File.mp3   (adding the double slash in the beginning of the uri)?

Comment: uri format is correct. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9562069/147530

Comment: How about listening to the MediaFailed event?  I was able to see an error in my environment using that.

Answer (score 6):

A couple of things to try.  Try the following code

```
var music = new MediaElement()
{
  AudioCategory = AudioCategory.ForegroundOnlyMedia,
  Source = new Uri(this.BaseUri, "Assets/MyMp3File.mp3")
};

// This is really the only difference, adding it to the visual tree
// LayoutRoot is the root of the visual tree, in the case, a grid in my XAML
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(music);

music.Play();
```

Adding it to the visual tree may be the key.  Put a break point on that to make sure your MediaElement has data in it.

Second (and actually happened to me so, that's why I mention it), I was developing on a Samsung device from //Build that has a docking station.  The audio jack on the device and the speakers are disabled when it is in the docking station.  You have to plug a headset into the docking station directly or remove it from the docking station to hear any sound.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the MediaElement in the visualTree before to make it play any media :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `x.autoplay = true`. With autoplay it will wait until it's loaded.