# Play One Audio File Simultaneously in Windows 8 (C#/XAML)

Tags: c#, audio, windows-8

I want to play many sound effect simultaneously from one audio file. So, I have an audio.wav file and I want to play it independently when I click a button. I have found similar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960952/play-two-sounds-simultaneously-in-windows-8-metro-app-c-xaml), but the solution not work for me because there is a lag between the sound. I have also try to use SharpDX from [here](http://loekvandenouweland.com/index.php/2012/11/playing-wav-files-in-a-xamlc-windows-store-app-using-sharpdx/) but it still have a lag between the sound and sometimes it won't play.

In Windows Phone, I use SoundEffect and it works perfecly. Any solution for my problem?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: What do you mean by lag? Maybe you shouldn't load it asynchronously.

Comment: There is a gap between one sound and another sound. So it feels like it waiting for something before it could play. I have use async but that still occur.