# Playing multiple audio files simultaneously in WP8

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8, simultaneous

I want to play two audio files simultaneously in WP8 from within the same app:

1. The first one will be launched by "BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();".
2. The second one will be launched by an HTML5 "audio" element within a Html file of the app.

The scenario would be something like this:

- When the user launches the app, the background music starts playing.
- When the user goes to a particular Html page of the app, its associated music starts playing.
- When the user switches the app or locks the screen, the music of that Html page stops, however, the background music keeps on playing until the app is closed.
- When the user comes back to that Html page again, its associated music starts playing along with the background music.

Appreciate your suggestions on this.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK with Mediaelement and BAP it's not possible to play two sounds simultanously, but I don't know about your idea. Have you tried to build simple App - first with webbrowser playing then add BAP?

Comment: Do you have a smaple code to share? I can test it if you wish.

Comment: You should have e-mail in your box within few minutes.

Comment: I would suggest you to search for xaudioplayer. It is a simpel c++ app that you can run eithin your application. With it you can play different songs/sfx at the same time. At the current version you get however the music has to be in the solution. But you can always expand it :)

Answer (score 1):

Together, we have tested a very simple App trying to play simultanously two audio files. The App worked like this:

- Play button has started audio file via BAP
- then we have navigated in `WebBrowser` to a page (located in IsolatedStorage) where there was an audio element
- and we have pushed play button in `WebBrowser` (still BAP playing in the background)

It turned out that `WebBrowser` uses BAP as a player, so after we have pressed the button, our poor BAP playing in the background was terminated and replaced with new fresh one from `WebBrowser`.

It means that our magnificent idea and superb plan had withered on the vine.

Answer (score -1):

So crap....

You'd need to build a player in your app so it could run simultaneously to the native one.

This explains why you cant run a gif and play music simultaneously.